# FindViewById not displaying id

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button that I want to clear certain fields after it is pressed. I have a button event that is supposed to display a question before the clear functionality is implemented. After the user confirms they want to clear the button then the button will clear the text in the fields. However, as of now the dialog isn't displaying. Below is a sample of my Clear Button function. Please let me know if you see anything I am not seeing.

```
        void btnPalletClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dialog = new Dialog(this, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialogNoActionBarMinWidth);

        View myView = View.Inflate(this, Resource.Layout.confirmation_dialog, null);
        myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtConfirmTitle).Text = "Clear Pallet";
        myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtConfirmMessage).Text = "Are you sure?";
        myView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.llQuantity).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        myView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdConfirmCancel).Click += delegate { dialog.Dismiss(); };

        myView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdConfirmOK).Click += delegate
        {
            dialog.SetContentView(myView);
            dialog.Show();
            txtPalletUNQ.Text = "";

            adapter.lstPallet.Clear();
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            txtPalletVTPID.Text = "";
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside the `Resource.Id.cmdConfirmOK` Click event and see if the delegate is getting triggered when you click the button? I think it may have to do with the fact that you're attaching a delegate within `btnPalletClear_Click`

Comment: Ok. I just did and it's not being triggered when inside the Resource.Id.cmdConfirmOk.

Comment: Yeah I think the trouble is from attaching an event while inside an event. Try doing like a `public bool ClearClicked = false;` at the class level, then when clear is clicked do `ClearClicked = true`. Then attach the `cmdConfirmOK` event from outside the `btnPalletClear_Click` method and inside `cmdConfirmOK` check `if (ClearClicked) { ... do your stuff here ... then ClearClicked = false; }` or something like that. Just guessing

Comment: I cut out the dialog.SetContentView(myview); , dialog.Show(); and pasted it outside of the cmdConfirmOk and it fixed it.

Comment: Uh, yeah, you were showing the dialog in the method that handles a click event from the dialog. Since you solved your own problem, add your solution as an answer and accept your own answer, so other don't stop here and look thinking it still needs a solution. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Unfortunately, I am not able to accept my own answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cut the dialog.SetContentView(myview), and dialog.Show() out and pasted it in outside of the cmdConfirmOk and it fixed it.